# Does Qt's d_ptr provoque sigsev?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I am working in a Qt application, and I wanted to thread the painting step of my program so I can zoom before it is over (if painting takes 5 second, it is veeery long to get to a detail of my QGraphicsView, that's why I wanted the user to be able to zoom a lot quickly)

But while I am moving my painting step into a separate thread, I get a lot of sigsev in the Qt source, and the lines point every time on a d_ptr access. So here's my question: is there a link between thread, d_ptr and sigsev?

Comment: are you painting into your widget directly from the other thread?? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#painting-in-threads

Comment: In my main thread, I wake up a QWaitCondition that makes the thread use the drawPolyline function. But I get sigsev in the very beginning of the function, the line is "if (!d->engine || pointCount < 2)"

Comment: And what is the paint device that the painter is working on (the painter whose `drawPolyline` is called in the other thread)?

Comment: I got a mainwindow with a QGraphicsView, and the painter is the one the QGraphicsItem get in their virtual QGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *)

Comment: that is exactly what the documentation prohibits. From a thread other than your main thread, you are allowed to paint only on a `QImage`, `QPrinter`, or a `QPicture`.

Comment: maybe you can prepare your zoomed item in a `QImage` in the other thread and send that image to the main thread to actually display it in the `QGraphicsItem `

Comment: Ok, I thought it was allowed, misunderstood the documentation... Thanks a lot for the help though, I will try your idea ;)